# Achieve -12~12V PWM Signal isolate

Tags: analog, pwm, opto-isolator

I have used IL300 to isolate 0~5V PWM signal before and it works great.
The circuit is shown below.

But now I need to isolate -12 ~ +12V PWM signal. Is there any possibility or suggested circuit to achieve it?

I have no idea about the negative voltage, but I have found some IC like Adum32XX etc. but the input voltage are all about 0~5 V.

[image: IL300 Isolator]

Comment: How is the PWM frequency?

Comment: Just for 1KHZ any suggest? thanks.

Comment: what output voltage do you need ?

Comment: positive voltage between 0v to 12v and negative between 0v to -12v  like 12v~-9v or  8v~-2v something like this

Comment: Why wouldn't you isolate the digital signal then do PWM->DC (if required) later?

Comment: Just add a RS232 self-powered converter, such as MAX3232 series, to your existing output.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit is for analog voltage with diode emission correction, to have precise analog isolation.

For PWM signal you don't need something that fancy.

If you need an output with 0-5V, you have nothing to do, as the low edge will be blocked by the emitting diode, it would be 0 and thereof output 0, the positive edge will work as normal.

Just make sure the diode has a maximum reverse voltage above 12V, or add an additional external diode.

Comment: Sorry ,I'm not good at English , I think u misunderstanding what i'm asking,what i'm saying for 0-5 is mean that  i can produce any voltage between 0 to 5 so as -12v ~+12v

Answer (score 0):

The Linear Opto has a CTR around 1% to 1.5% so a buffer is needed that can handle 24V swing.

Fortunately there are new Rail-to-Rail CMOS Op Amps rated for 40V, so you may use isolated +/-12V or less.

[OPA991](https://www.ti.com/product/OPA991)
ACTIVE
Order now
40-V, single 4.5MHz, rail-to-rail input/output, low-offset-voltage, low-noise op amp